# How to continue a sequence when inserting

Tags: sql, t-sql, insert

I have tried to simplify my question with the following example:

I have a table with the following data:

```
Marker     Name            Location
1          Eric Benson     Mixed
2          John Smith      Rural
3          A David         Rural
4          B John          Mixed
```

And i want to insert into the table:

```
Name            Location
Andy Jones      Mixed
Ian Davies      Rural
```

How can i continue the sequencein the Marker column to end up with:

```
Marker     Name            Location
1          Eric Benson     Mixed
2          John Smith      Rural
3          A David         Rural
4          B John          Mixed
5          Andy Jones      Mixed
6          Ian Davies      Rural
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that an [identity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) or [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15) wouldn't address? There are good reasons that the functionality is built into the database and that trying to reinvent it is a bad idea, e.g. handling transaction rollbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you make this with a Stored Procedure you can ask the max of the Marker before to insert.
(That only works if the Marker Column is not  [identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15))

Like This:

```
declare @max_marker int
set @max_marker=isnull((select max(marker) from table),0)
--Insert comes here
Insert into table (Marker,Name,Location) Values(@max_marker+1,'Andy Jones','Mixed')
```